# customize UIBarButtonItem to have no border?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icons, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to create a `UIBarButtonItem` that looks like the "list" button on the iPod.app
so I have 2 questions:

1. How can I set the icon to look like the iPod's one? I saw it in other apps, but couldn't    find it on xcode. (the icon that appears on the right side of the navigation bar on the "now playing" screen)
2. how can I set the `UIBarButtonItem`'s image to show without it's default border?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding custom view with button you want as a subview to your bar;

```
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myBar.bounds];
UIbutton* myBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[myBtn setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myView addSubview:myBtn];
[myBar addSubview:myView];
```